# Type mismatch using Split function on VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variant, mismatch

For some reason that I can't find, I get a mismatch error while trying to print the array, I need a way to see how the array is defined.

```
        Dim x As Variant 
        x = Split(ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Formula, "")
        Debug.Print x
        For j = 1 To Len(ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Formula)
            
            If x(j) = "G" Then
            
                x(j) = "H"
            
            End If
            
        Next j
```

Comment: Btw, `Split` returns a zero-based array.

Comment: `Debug.Print x`: you can't `Debug.Print` an array. You need to `Debug.Print` its individual elements. Using `Join` is another option.

Comment: `split` with an empty string as the delimiter just returns the string.

Comment: Btw, `Split` with an empty string will not split the text at all.

Comment: Thank you all, I didn't know those things.